# Error while trying to open .xls files

Tags: vba, excel

I have some information in a .xls file (I downloaded it from SAP) and I need to paste it in a .xlsm file.

I'm trying to open that file like always but I have the following error:

```
Run-time error ‘-2147221080 (800401a8)’:

The file format and extension of ‘file.xls’ don’t match. The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source, don’t open it. Do you want to open it anyway?
```

and two options: End and Debug. If I choose debug, I get the following error:

```
Run-time error ‘-2147221080 (800401a8)’: Automation error
```

I couldn't find anything in Google. How can I fix it? It's impossible to have the information in another format that is not .xls

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file with either `.xlsx` and/or `.xlsm` extensions?

Comment: Yes, and it's impossible to open then. I think it's because it has some encrypted information or something like that.

Comment: can you show some of the surrounding code...are you opening and closing workbooks for example?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to open the file with notepad? Notepad can open almost any file. It could be that the content will show strange characters though.

Comment: mmh.. You mean transforming the .xls into .txt and opening a .txt? Is it impossible to open .xls?

Comment: If it is a real xls you will probably see a lot of strange characters. But maybe it will show that the file is in fact not xls.

Comment: It's real xls. It's how it's imported from SAP. Is anything to do?

I mean, I can open that file in Excel and see the information, but then I can't open it using VBA. Maybe it's another way to open it, I don't know

Comment: So you can open the file in Excel? And what if you open it and then save it as an xlsx file and then try to use it?

Comment: I can open the file in Excel MANUALLY, but when I use Workbook.Open, I can open a .xlsx file but when I try to open a .xls file it fails and gives the error I posted in the main post